# CV concerns about misleading admissions committees on accident. Are concerns like this warranted at all?

Tags: publications, research-process, career-path, cv, poster

Back again with a bit of a follow up to this post, albeit I'm not concerned about degree revocation this time:

[May have embellished my CV and resume by mistake after I was admitted to MA and Ph.D programs. Could either of my degrees be revoked?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/204328/may-have-embellished-my-cv-and-resume-by-mistake-after-i-was-admitted-to-ma-and)

I just realized I cited a poster from my undergrad incorrectly. I accidentally said I presented a poster at an undergraduate research symposium when it was actually a bi-annual psychology poster conference. I also put myself as the first author even though I didn't remember the order that was agreed upon (although I distinctly remember my poster partner didn't mind the order so I probably just went "why not?" even though that order mattered and I didn't know it at the time I made the entry). In case it's also important, I presented this poster for an extra credit assignment in a Cognitive Neuroscience class. The TA for the class guided us through the whole thing and I honestly didn't feel like I deserved to be an author even though I agreed to help and did a poor job at doing so (given how I walked away with a C in the class overall. I wasn't a good undergrad student). When I reviewed the old email exchanges, I definitely don't feel like I deserve it whatsoever and may take it off my CV even though the conference organizers encouraged all of us to list the posters on our CV.

Problem is... I got admitted to 6/8 Master's programs and I'm worried that poster may have given them an impression I did more than I actually did and that could've got me in the door when I otherwise shouldn't have done so.

I also had a different instance one time during my Master's program where I listed myself as an "Investigator" (this was how the campus where I was a research assistant called it) and was corrected by the MA program director to list it as Research Assistant (even though I was called an investigator by my lab, albeit the duties were the same as a research assistant). The reason for the correction was because the program director said it looked like I did more than I actually did even though I wasn't a Principal Investigator (some context - the PI for this lab was German so he may have just called his research assistants the equivalent term, investigators, and I didn't know it since that was my first lab).

Anyway, I'm concerned about someone noticing this and potentially obstructing me currently. I know I have two degrees (BS, MA) and I'm not worried about those getting revoked at all based on the previous answers to my last question. Could this get me into some trouble though?

If this violates any rules like last time, feel free to close it. I'm just concerned about presenting my work in an honest manner and don't want it to affect me if I pre-emptively address it.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt you have much to worry about. I think that these kinds of details on your cv didn't have much effect one way or the other on your admission decisions. I can't imagine someone going back to reread your cv and question that decision.

So update the cv and be more careful from now on.